# Create both associated models from the form of the "belongs_to" one (rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rails-activerecord

With the hope that my consecutive questions are not a problem for anyone, I want to ask for your assistance on how to achieve the creation of two models from one form.

The two associated models are

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :company
  attr_accessible :company_id
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  has_many :employees
end
```

and what I want is to create a company when I am creating an employee and the input company doesn't already exist. Without the "when the company doesn't already exist" requirement, this is my code:

`employees/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for(@employee) do |f| %>
  <%= simple_form_for(@company) do |cf| %>
    <%= f.input :name, label: 'Employee Name', :required => true %>
    <%= cf.input :title, label: 'Company Name', :required => true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and `employees_controller.rb`

```
def new
  @employee = Employee.new
  @company = Company.new
end
```

[...]

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])
  @company = Company.new(params[:company])
  @employee.company_id = params[:company_id]

  respond_to do |format|
    if @employee.save
      format.html { redirect_to @employee, notice: 'Employee was successfully created.' }
      format.json { render json: @employee, status: :created, location: @employee }
    else
      format.html { render action: "new" }
      format.json { render json: @employee.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
    end
  end
end
```

This some kind of association between the employee and the company (that of the employee "holding" the company id) but it doesn't create (or, if I understand well, doesn't actually save) the company.

If I go on and add `@company.save` before the id assignment, everything seems okay. Is it, however? Shouldn't I render the `new company form` and have everything saved after that is submitted?

I have been searching online all day for the solution but in every case the implementation was performed the opposite way: How to create a bunch of employees from a new company form.

Comment: You can't put a form inside a form,  so I'd start be rethinking the presentation of the inputs using only ONE simple_form_for

Comment: "You can't" as in "it's not best practice"? Because the fields are actually displayed and the attributes are being sent fine as well.

Comment: I'd say it's more severe than 'not best practice'  it's specifically NOT allowed by official W3C XHTML specification.  It breaks browsers in subtle and hard to detect ways!

Comment: Thanks for the notice, my bad for "blindly" following other people's code. For the record, I changed the inner form to "simple_fields_for". (updated on question)

Comment: I posted an answer,  refresh it because the first version had a bug!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, after a lot of experimenting, I 've came down to this:

`employees/_form.html.erb`

```
<%= simple_form_for(@employee) do |f| %>
  <%= simple_fields_for(@company) do |cf| %>
    <%= f.input :name, label: 'Employee Name', :required => true %>
    <%= cf.input :title, label: 'Company Name', :required => true %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

`employees_controller.rb`

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])

  @company = Customer.find_or_create_by_name(params[:company][:name])
  @company.employees << @employee
  @company.save

  @employee.save
end
```

It is slightly more elegant than the answer provided by @RadBrad but also influenced by it.

*if you need to know how to actually fill in all the attributes of the `company` model, follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15887732/how-to-redirect-from-one-action-of-controller-a-to-an-action-of-controller-b-and)*

Answer (score 1):

There are lot's of ways to go,  here is one:

```
def Employee << ActiveRecord::Base
  def title
    return nil
  end
end

<%= simple_form_for(@employee) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :name, label: 'Employee Name', :required => true %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: 'Company Name', :required => true %>
  <%= f.submit 'Create'
<% end %>
```

Then in your EmployeesController:

```
def create
   co = Company.find_by_title(params[:employee][:title]).first
   unless co
      co = Company.new({:company=>params[:employee][:title]})
   end
   co.employees.build({:name=>params[:employee][:name]});
   co.save
end
```

Comment: The `employee` model doesn't have a `:title` attribute so the above form gives an `undefined method 'title' for Employee`.

Comment: You're comment isn't clear, I posted a fix to show how to fake simple_form_for into putting up attributes that don't really exist in the model

Comment: I commented before you added the `def title` method in the `Employee model`. Although this approach looks like "cheating" to inexperienced me, it makes total sense. Thanks a lot - will accept as soon as I test it.