# How to redirect from one action of controller A to an action of controller B and back in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redirect, controller, action, back

I have two associated models, `Employee` and `Company`:

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name

  belongs_to :company
  attr_accessible :company_id
end

class Company < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :industry, :owner

  has_many :employees
end
```

What I want to implement is that when, in the new employee form, the user types a company name that doesn't exist he/she should be redirected to the new company form, with the name field already filled with the value of the previous form, fill it in for the company to be created and then get redirected to the "employee successfully created" page (but if and only if the company is created first).

I have managed to create a company at the same time the employee is created, with the below code:

```
def create
  @employee = Employee.new(params[:employee])

  @company = Customer.find_or_create_by_name(params[:company][:name])
  @company.employees << @employee
  @company.save

  @employee.save
end
```

However, this doesn't give me the option to fill in the rest of the company information.

Experimenting with `redirect_to`, I have also managed to send the user to the edit company form.

```
# one way to tell if the company has all its attributes filled
if @company.industry.blank?
  redirect_to edit_company_path(@company), notice: "Please edit the company details" and return
end
```

*the `and return` statement is necessary as otherwise I get a "The redirect_to was called multiple times" error*

However, this is not the desired behaviour - for two reasons:

- The employee is created even when the company is not.
- The user is not informed about the employee creation.

So, my thinking is that I am redirecting to the company controller and the create action the right way and that I should somehow redirect back to where I was (right before the `@employee.save`) in the employee controller. But how? Also, is that the best and "most-rails" way to do it?

Comment: Check out routing http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option I see is to save employee data in session (`session[:temp_employee] = params[:employee]`), then redirect to creating the company. In the company controller, after the company is saved you could check if employee is present in the session then redirect client back to create action of the employees controller.

This would additionally require you to:

- Enable access to create action via path (like: `get 'create', to: 'employees#create'`)
- In the employees create action take for attributes from session variable if it is present, otherwise fallback to the params hash.