# Form and Save new record to association model in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 model (3 tables)

Campaign , rel_campaign_site and Site (Campaign,site  have many rel_camp_site)
rel_camp_site table have camp_id and site_id

I want to make a form to create new Campaign but I dont know how to put the site_id in the form (in check box)

and when campaign created , rel_camp_site auto create new record with camp_id is the id of the created campaign,site_id is the chosen checked box in form

please help me.Im newbie in rails :(

Comment: Hey Duong, a couple of months ago I asked something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721701/create-both-associated-models-from-the-form-of-the-belongs-to-one-rails/15888317#15888317

Comment: thank you,Im working on it and still cant find the way out :(

Comment: If you show us your code we might be able to guide you.

Comment: thank you gúy,I did it in the view,turn out that the problem is the fields_for
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html

Comment: thank you so much for ur kindness.It did help me with my searching @sebkomianos